# "Not to put too fine a point on it"

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> – What did she say? – **Not to put too fine a point on it**, she said you sexually harassed her.

This expression means 'used to apologise for a possibly impolite statement one is making.' But why does this sequence of words mean that? What does mean *to put a point on something*? And then how is *a fine point* different from *a point*?

Comment: possibly related question:
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34637/what-does-the-phrase-the-fine-point-mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No one seems to know exactly what the literal meaning of the words is. That meaning has been lost in time. It's just a fixed expression these days.

http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2009/09/fine-tuning-2.html
http://throwgrammarfromthetrain.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/dickenss-fine-point.html

It seems that the language is figurative. A fine point, whatever that is, is the opposite of something that is blunt. So, not to put a fine point on something is to be blunt, and in fact you can just say it like that:

> To be blunt, she said you sexually harassed her.
>   To put it bluntly, she said you sexually harassed her.

I would say it like that personally.

Comment: By *to be blunt* do you mean *rude* (saying exactly what you think without caring about people's feelings)?

Comment: @Graduate, yes, _blunt_ means not caring about someone's feelings, but it's different to _rude_ I think because rudeness means you are being intentionally hurtful. If you are blunt, in contrast, you aren't trying to be hurtful.

Comment: One native speaker explained me the difference between *rude* and *mean* in a similar way, but she regarded *rudeness* as not intentional. If you are *rude*, it is not intentional, maybe it is a trait of your culture. If you are *mean*, you do it intentionally.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't mean *used to apologize for a possibly impolite statement one is making*.

It means that without going into the specific details of the event, I'll shortly paraphrase what she said.

So *to put a fine point on it*, would include saying how the person sexually harassed her. For example, she said you touched her inappropriately on the chest.

Comment: This. It's equivalent to "long story short..."

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning is lost to the mists of time, but speculation as to the origin of the current figurative use is possible by reference either to a quill pen (though there are no reliable sources to support this), or by reference to a sharp pencil as used in drawing (again, there are no sources to support this).

However, from the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/not-to-put-too-fine-a-point-on-it?q=Not%20to%20put%20too%20fine%20a%20point%20on%20it), the phrase means:

> To speak bluntly

and the entry continues "figuratively, with reference to the sharpening of a weapon, tool, etc.".

Answer (score 0):

I use not to put too fine  a point on it ironically because in addition to being blunt I make a number of statements to illustrate the point and will  provide a number of examples. I have always felt that the statement not to put too fine a point on it includes being blunt and also brief in your statement and I am usually not brief. In short I am making a little fun of myself for being so loquacious